# cancan authorization rule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

I have a cancan authorization problem.

My scenario is like this.

```
User has_one Student
```

In StudentsController I have I get user and student like this

```
@user = User.where(:username => params[:username]).first
@student = @user.student
```

Now how can I write cancan authorization rule to edit/update **@student record** so that the **logged user can only edit his student record**, provided that **@user** may or may not be the logged in user. Its just the user with the username form params.

I hope the question is clear :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the wiki for CanCan:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

You should be able to define that ability in the ability model by doing something like:

```
can :edit, Student, :user_id => user.id
```